# List box context menu

Tags: c++, mfc, listbox, contextmenu

How do I add a context menu in a list box in MFC? I don't see any WM_CONTEXTMENU handler in list box's properties. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I followed this tutorial [MFC List Control: How to use a context menu in a list control?](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=231221). The tutorial says to derive my own class from CListBox which I did, but now how do I add list box of my derived class to the dialog?

Answer (score 3):

Put an `OnContextMenu` handler in the parent class.  Then add a popup menu

Edit To add the `OnContextMenu` handler, add an event handler to the PARENT window (ie not the list class). This is most easily done through the resource editor. Go to the properties page then go to the messages section. Then add a function for `WM_CONTEXTMENU`.

```
void CYourDialog::OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint point)
{
    CListCtrl* pList = (CListCtrl*)GetDlgItem( ID_YOUR_LIST );

    if ( (CWnd*)pList == pWnd )
    {
        CMenu menu;
        // Create your menu items.

        int retVal  = menu.TrackPopupMenu( TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_NONOTIFY | TPM_RETURNCMD, point.x, point.y, this );
        
        // Handle your returns here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since my edit was rejected with the rationale of "changing too much", I will put my proposal here because in my opinion the original code promotes bad coding practices.

```
void CYourDialog::OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint point)
{
    int CtrlID = pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID();

    if (CtrlID == ID_YOUR_LIST) {
        CMenu menu;
        // Create your menu items...
        int retVal = menu.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_NONOTIFY | TPM_RETURNCMD, point.x, point.y, this);
        // Handle selected options here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the following steps:

1. Add

```
ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU()
```

to

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

So you will have something like

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

2. Add the Context Menu function in the header file:

```
afx_msg void OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint point)
```

3. Then add the Context Menu function, as suggested in the article:

```
void CMyDialog::OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint point)
{
    CListCtrl* pList = (CListCtrl*)GetDlgItem( ID_YOUR_LIST );

    if ( (CWnd*)pList == pWnd )
    {
        CMenu menu;
        // Create your menu items.

        int retVal  = menu.TrackPopupMenu( TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_NONOTIFY | TPM_RETURNCMD, point.x, point.y, this );

        // Handle your returns here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler for your dialog window. That will generate this:

```
void YourDialogClass::OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint point) {
  ...
}
```

`pWnd` will point to the window/control in which the user right clicked the mouse.

Comment: but where do I add that? I mean there is no class for list box

Comment: i can't see the class for list box in my source code. there are only two classes CDialog, CWinApp

Comment: @Manzoor Ahmed, I edited my answer. The method will be placed in your dialog class.

Comment: why should I add the handler in the dialog class, where is the list box class? please see my edit

Comment: @Manzoor Ahmed, you don't really have to derive a class for every control that need a context menu. Goz wrote an example for you, try it.

Answer (score -1):

If you followed the tutorial to derive you own class, make sure `ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU()` is added to the new class message map.

To add a list box of your derived class, you simply add a variable for your ListBox control and specify the variable class as your derived class.

However I think @Goz's answer is also a valid solution, and a simpler one.