# Can Right-mouse click events be detected on a MFC Button control?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to create a dialog with multiple buttons, which change color on left and right clicks respectively.
So, how can I handle the right click event for specific buttons ??

`ON_RBUTTONDOWN` doesn't work for specific buttons.

Comment: http://www.go4expert.com/articles/mouse-button-event-handler-t381/

Comment: Buttons don't handle right button. You need to sub-class.

Comment: @Himanshu please post your comment as an answer, so as to help other users, having the same query in future :)

Comment: @TarangGupta, okay i will post it soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As MFC does not allow to trap all the events on the CButton control but there some commonly used events like BN_CLICKED and BN_DOUBLECLICKED. So to trap a right mouse button events on a CButton MFC you need to derive a new class from the CButton.

MyButton.h

```
#if !defined(AFX_MYBUTTON_H__46A1ECCC_0FAD_485A_B6B8_C21B6538148E__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_MYBUTTON_H__46A1ECCC_0FAD_485A_B6B8_C21B6538148E__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000
// MyButton.h : header file
// CMyButton window

class CMyButton : public CButton  //CMyButton  =>derive from the CButton.
{
// Construction
public:
    CMyButton();

// Attributes
public:

// Operations
public:

// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CMyButton)
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
public:
    virtual ~CMyButton();

    // Generated message map functions
protected:
    //{{AFX_MSG(CMyButton)
    afx_msg void OnRButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
    //}}AFX_MSG

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

#endif // !defined(AFX_MYBUTTON_H__46A1ECCC_0FAD_485A_B6B8_C21B6538148E__INCLUDED_)
```

MyButton.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyButton.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CMyButton

CMyButton::CMyButton()
{
}

CMyButton::~CMyButton()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyButton, CButton)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyButton)
    ON_WM_RBUTTONUP()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CMyButton message handlers

void CMyButton::OnRButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    NMHDR hdr;
    hdr.code = NM_RCLICK;
    hdr.hwndFrom = this->GetSafeHwnd();
    hdr.idFrom = GetDlgCtrlID();
    TRACE("OnRButtonUp");
    this->GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_NOTIFY, (WPARAM)hdr.idFrom, (LPARAM)&hdr);
}
```

Now in your Dialog class you need to trap the Message that your CMyButton passes. The message passed is NM_RCLICK and you capture it as

```
ON_NOTIFY(NM_RCLICK, IDC_BUTTON1, OnRClicked)
```

Your member function must be declared with the following prototype:

```
afx_msg void OnRClicked( NMHDR * pNotifyStruct, LRESULT * result );
```

For more details you can go through link [mouse-button-event-handler](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/mouse-button-event-handler-t381/)

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer works, I find it much easier to trap WM_CONTEXT_MENU, which is possible for any control with no new classes required, and many fewer lines of added code. Here's one example of how to do it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63633383/9655696