# Upgrade MFC CListBox control with ON_WM_RBUTTONDOWN so dialog can handle message directly

Tags: c++, mfc, clistbox

I have wondered about how limited is the provided set of messages controllers for `CListBox` control. I am already using `ON_LBN_SELCHANGE` in the message map of the `CDialog` containing this control.

I also would like to use `ON_WM_RBUTTONDOWN`, so I have derived a `class CMyListBox : public CListBox`, so now i can map that message inside the class, but I would like to map it to the dialog in the same way of `ON_LBN_SELCHANGE` works.

My question is whether is possible to re-send that message to parent dialog, so I can handle it from `CDialog` message map, and what is the best way of doing this (send_message, post_message or is there a better notification mechanism)?

Comment: Possibly a case for using `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/inputmsg/wm-parentnotify)?

Comment: @Adrian Mole: It may be, please would you like to update your comment to a formal response so people could vote it? There you could explain how your proposal is used: How to send the ```WM_PARENTNOTIFY``` to CDialog? How to pack the argunment of controller to generate the message?

Comment: Also can’t you just use the contextmenu handler and test the parent handle?  Not tested.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509120/list-box-context-menu This is the easiest. Detect right click by testing the window passed against your list box. All done in dialog.

Comment: @Andrew Truckle: Thank you, your solution is also valid, I have already checked and "WM_CONTEXTMENU" on dialog message map works fine in this case

Comment: Later I may add it as a answer as a second solution.

Comment: @Andrew Truckle: I would appreciate that

Comment: @Pablo I have just added my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your control to send `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` messages to the parent dialog box (it doesn't, by default) and add an override of the [`OnParentNotify()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#onparentnotify) to your dialog class. The basic procedure would be as outlined below.

First, you'll need to remove the `WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY` style from your list-box control, so that it sends the required message to its parent. There are several ways to do this but one quite easy way is to modify the "ex-style" in your `OnInitDialog` override, like this:

```cpp
BOOL MyDialog::OnInitDialog(void)
{
    CDialog::OnInitDIalog(); // Call base class
    //...
    // Other code you need
    //
    CWnd* pList = GetDlgItem(IDC_MYLISTBOX); // Use the resource ID of the listbox
    LONG_PTR exstyle = GetWindowLongPtr(pList->m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    // Remove the WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY bit ...
    exstyle &= ~WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY;
    SetWindowLongPtr(pList->m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exstyle); // Set new style
    //...
    return TRUE; // Assuming you don't explicitly set the focus
}
```

Then, you'll need to add `ON_WM_PARENTNOTIFY` to your dialog's message map:

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyDialog, CDialog)
    //...
    ON_WM_PARENTNOTIFY()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Finally, the handler to intercept the notification:

```cpp
void MyDialog::OnParentNotify(UINT message, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CDialog::OnParentNotify(message, lParam); // Always best to call base class for MFC!
    if (message == WM_RBUTTONDOWN) {
        // Here, we can handle the right-button click!
        // lParam will be the cursor position (x in LOWORD and y in HIWORD)
        // NOTE: See the caveat mentioned below!
    }
}
```

One (potentially troublesome) issue with this approach is that (as you may have noticed) there is no information passed to the handler function about which control the notification came from. If you only have one control in your dialog that has this behaviour enabled, then that's OK; otherwise, you'll have to do some trickery (using the cursor position given and the control's window rectangle) to determine which control has sent the message.

Comment: @Pablo I have done a short test of the above method and it appears that the cursor position is sent in terms of the parent dialog's client coordinates. That makes it slightly easier to get the active control, using the `GetWindowRect()` function, probably.

Comment: Ok, that was expected as it happens with some other controls. By the way, it makes slighter harder to get which item has been clicked inside the CListBox, but it is nothing that old good ```ScreenToClient``` can easily solve.

Answer (score 3):

I thought that I would also show you this approach as an alternative which would save on the need for deriving your own `CListBox` class.

1. Select your dialog class.
2. Select the Messages icon in the Properties pane.
3. Locate [`WM_CONTEXTMENU`](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/windows/win32/menurc/wm-contextmenu) in the list and add the handler via the drop-down menu.

[image: Add Handler]

The description for this handler says:

> Notifies a window that the user desires a context menu to appear. The user may have clicked the right mouse button (right-clicked) in the window, pressed Shift+F10 or pressed the applications key (context menu key) available on some keyboards.
>
> `wParam` - A handle to the window in which the user right-clicked the mouse. This can be a child window of the window receiving the message. For more information about processing this message, see the Remarks section.

You will need to uncomment the parameters that you want to use in the handler that is generated. For example:

```
void CMFCApplication4Dlg::OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint /*point*/)
{
    if (pWnd->GetSafeHwnd() == m_lbList.GetSafeHwnd())
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("User right-clicked on the listbox control"));
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Of-course, there is nothing wrong with deriving your own class like you have done and handling the mouse buttons and using the notify system. And I am not saying that this approach is any better. I simply show it as an alternative to detect a right-click on a control on your dialog.

---

Note:
There are other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1509167/2287576) here on SO about using this approach but the ones I found did not show screenshots.

Comment: Congratulations for mentioning `WM_CONTEXTMENU`. Handling the right-click message directly bypasses a lot of standard Windows behaviors.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and explanation. You have stated cristal clear your proposal, and also have provided some screenshots with apport great help. Nice job!